# Android - Onclick View with button and text

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, anko

I have a custom button that I build using anko DSL:

```
fun customButton(label: String): View {
    return UI {
        verticalLayout {
            button {
                id = BTN_SERVICE_ITEM_ID
            }.lparams(dip(64), dip(64))

            textView {
                text = label
            }.lparams(wrapContent, wrapContent)
        }
    }.view
}
```

then I add `setOnClickListener` on that button

```
val customButton = customButton("service 1")

layout.addView(customButton)

customButton.setOnClickListener {
    toast("clicked")
}
```

when I click the button, the toast is not shown. But when the area of the custom button is clicked, the toast is shown.

I know I can use `findViewById` to get the button then add `setOnClickListener` to it. But, is there any method so I can just attach onClickListener to the view?

EDIT:

I already try to add `isEnabled=false`, `isClickable=false`, `isFocusable=false` , `isActivated=false` and setOnClickListener(null) on the button. Still no luck.

Comment: your customButton is not a button. It is a layout that contains a button. You're setting a clicklistener on the layout, not the button

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I know that. That what I was searching for. But the button ignoring the layout `onClickListener`. I also try to remove the `onClickListener` on the button so it capture the `onClickListener` on the layout. But, still no luck.

Comment: Total unresponsivness

Comment: @mTak dude, what's your problem? Not everyone have same time zone as yours. It's already night in here. And I'm planning to answer all of your questions/suggestions tomorrow. And now I misuse this comment section because of you.

Comment: You can leave a comment if you're unavailable. And how did your question appear again by a different username?

Comment: On where? Can you give me the link. I don't have any other account.

Comment: This is it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244951/android-click-event-view-with-button-and-text#comment89469645_51244951)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be just to pass an instance of `View.OnClickListener` to your method `customButton`.

I am not familiar with anko syntax, but it should look similar to this:

```
fun customButton(label: String, clickListener: View.OnClickListener): View {
    return UI {
        verticalLayout {
            button {
                id = BTN_SERVICE_ITEM_ID
                onClickListener = clickListener
            }.lparams(dip(64), dip(64))

            textView {
                text = label
            }.lparams(wrapContent, wrapContent)
        }
    }.view
}
```

After all, if you're up to making a dedicated method to create a button, why not to use full of it :)

Comment: Aahhh. This never cross my mind. Gonna check this tomorrow.

Comment: I can't use `onClickListener = clickListener`, but use `this.setOnClickListener { clickListener() }` instead. And change the variable `clickListener` to a function so it become `clickListener: () -> Unit`. And then to use it `val button = customButton("YeY") { toast("YeY") }`